# How to shared items in different testing files

Tags: go, testing

I want to shared items in many different testing files, just like global variable but only in testing scope.

```
./1_test.go
./2_test.go
./3_test.go

// shared between these files
var item *test.global
```

Comment: You share variables between test files within the same package by declaring the variable in one of those files at the package level. Proper Go test files are not included in the final binary, therefore a variable declared in one of those test files will NOT be available to code declared in a normal file.

Comment: I tried to do this before, and these three test files are in the same package name, but the item in one file can not be shared for three.

Comment: It may not be shared if you are executing only a specific test rather than the whole package. Can you show how you are executing the `go test` tool?

Comment: I just do the unit not the integration testing, `go test 1_test.go` e.g.

Comment: Well with `go test 1_test.go` you're essentially telling the tool to only include that specific file in the test, i.e. you're telling it to ignore all the other `_test.go` files. See how this works when you test the whole package: https://imgur.com/p0qqV55

Comment: For details see: https://pkg.go.dev/cmd/go#hdr-Test_packages & https://pkg.go.dev/cmd/go#hdr-Package_lists_and_patterns. *"As a special case, if the package list is a list of .go files from a single directory, the command is applied to a single synthesized package made up of exactly those files, ignoring any build constraints in those files and ignoring any other files in the directory. "* -- Unless you know exactly what you're doing you should *not* pass a file to any of the `go <action>` tools, including `go test`.

Comment: Is it possible to change the `Value` to `value` to shared this variable?

Comment: Are you asking whether or not it has to be exported (i.e. start with upper case letter)? No it doesn't have to. You can share unexported variables between files within the same package just as well as exported: https://imgur.com/BbO6srl

Answer (score 3):

Let's say the current package name is `cpx`, you can use the package name `cpx_test` for all 3 test files. Go allows 1 package (with one or more files) and 1 test package (with one or more files) in the same directory.

```
cpx
├── cpx.go
├── cpx_1_test.go
├── cpx_2_test.go
└── cpx_3_test.go
```

By using this, you can declare global variables in cpx_test scope that are only limited to the 3 test files. You should import original package in test as an external package.

```golang
import "gitlab.com/VagueCoder0to.n/Project/cpx"
```

Let's say we have the following snippet in cpx_1_test.go

```golang
var (
    complex1, complex2, complex3 *cpx.Complex
)

func TestAdd(t *testing.T) {
    complex1 = &cpx.Complex{
        Real: 1,
        Imag: 10,
    }

    complex2 = &cpx.Complex{
        Real: 2,
        Imag: 9,
    }

    complex3 = cpx.ComplexAdd(complex1, complex2)
}
```

The 3 variables can be used by other 2 files as well. But the limitations here are:

1. Testing the `cpx_2_test.go` and `cpx_3_test.go` file separately may give you false errors as the initiation of variables is done in `cpx_1_test.go` alone.
2. Order of test files in execution matters.

```
go test cpx_1_test.go cpx_2_test.go cpx_3_test.go
```

3. Order of test cases also matters. The test `TestAdd` should be tested before any other test function.

Alternatively, I use the sub-tests in use-cases, which goes against your initial idea, but it makes sense if the unit tests are related. i.e., have some similar classification, say `TestOperators`, with sub tests `TestAdd`, `TestSubtract`, `TestMultiply`, `TestDivision`. The [testing](https://pkg.go.dev/testing) package provides `Run` method on type `*testing.T` to define sub tests.

```golang
func TestOperators(t *testing.T) {
    var complex1, complex2, complex3 *cpx.Complex
    complex1 = &cpx.Complex{
        Real: 1,
        Imag: 10,
    }

    complex2 = &cpx.Complex{
        Real: 2,
        Imag: 9,
    }

    t.Run("TestAdd", func(t *testing.T) {
        complex3 = cpx.ComplexAdd(complex1, complex2)
        assert.NotNil(t, complex3)
    })

    t.Run("TestSubtract", func(t *testing.T) {
        complex3 = cpx.ComplexSubtract(complex1, complex2)
        // Tests here
    })

    t.Run("TestMultiply", Multiply)

    // More sub tests...

}

func Multiply(t *testing.T) {
    // Tests here
}
```

You may use inline anonymous functions (like in `TestAdd` and `TestSubtract`) or general test cases (as in `TestMultiply`). If using functions, make sure the function name (identifier) doesn't start with the work "**Test**". Else, go tools will consider that as a separate test case. Output will be:

```
go test -v ./...
?       gitlab.com/VagueCoder0to.n/Project  [no test files]
=== RUN   TestOperators
=== RUN   TestOperators/TestAdd
=== RUN   TestOperators/TestSubtract
=== RUN   TestOperators/TestMultiply
--- PASS: TestOperators (0.00s)
    --- PASS: TestOperators/TestAdd (0.00s)
    --- PASS: TestOperators/TestSubtract (0.00s)
    --- PASS: TestOperators/TestMultiply (0.00s)
PASS
ok      gitlab.com/VagueCoder0to.n/Project/cpx  0.004s
```